# Subscription should include answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, community, subscription

At my company we actively monitor the public mailinglists that we host. We are very eager to fully embrace and promote Stackoverflow as an area for Q&A about our product.
In the community we have a lot of people who are now used to monitor the email-flow of the mailinglist.
Now, I am well aware that SO is not a substitute for a mailinglist and that certain things are simply inherently different and hard to map between formats.

One area that is sorely missing (as far as my search of meta could uncover) is monitoring of answers, many times an answer is not very clear-cut, multidisciplinary and/or can use some improvement (which is a big plus of SO). What I'd really love to offer to many of our members is the following:

**Allow users to subscribe (email or rss) to all questions *and* answers on a certain tag**

Comment: "This also allows senior community members to hold back their answer and allow a relative junior to answer (which is an invaluable teaching tool) and correct where required." Huh? Why would you want that?

Comment: i dont think it will gonna helpful . In top tags there are thousand of question and answer post every day  ... or in other word i dont want to see 4000 mail/per day however you can feed question in a tag but there is no way for answer

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby, I prefer a system in which you have more than just a couple of answerers, but to involve all community members in giving answers.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer, for top tags this will indeed lead to a torrent of info, just like the RSS feed of questions will. Dare I suggest that we leave that as a choice to the user? :)

Comment: @VonLion: The main goal of SE is to provide *one correct* answer. Everything else is, *in theory* noise. In practice the accepted answer is not always the best and there are better ones down the list. Also in practice it's a smell if a question receives more then 7 (made up number) answers, and somebody should look into the question if it should be closed.

Comment: Ok, these comments are focusing on the last bit of info I've provided, that was not my intention, I am removing that sentence since it clearly is controversial and not the core of my question at all.

Answer (score 1):

One major purpose of providing the newsletters in the first place is obviously to bring users to the website in the hope that he or she will contribute. Although it may be more *convenient* to see answers in email, it does not align with the goals of the site.

Furthermore, there would be no easy way to pick one answer to show for each question. As stated in the comments, many accepted answers are surpassed in upvotes by a different response. The best way to show any answers would thus be to show them all, and most people would rather just follow the link if they're interested.

My final point against this feature (though certainly not the last that could be argued) is that this would discourage answers from receiving votes. If you read an amazing answer that solves all your problems, more people will consider it an inconvenience to follow a link to a topic they no longer care about. Same for a bad answer.

StackOverflow is based on having an active community of users that use the site to encourage further contributions, and a newsletter with questions that provoke visitors is one way to get them to come, and should definitely remain so.